# MySQL ERROR #1415 - Not allowed to return a result set from a function

Tags: mysql, sql

My question is about a function returning only one value but I still get this error, so What I'm supposed to get is average day between the order date and the shipped date, the query is doing that and returning me only one value which is the average. If I use just the SELECT statement outside the of the function I get one column/row answer of 8.4920.

How can I fix that please. Thanks.

```
DELIMITER //
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS OrderFulfilmel//

CREATE FUNCTION  OrderFulfilmel(average int) RETURNS DOUBLE Deterministic
BEGIN

SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(ShippedDate, OrderDate)) AS averageDay

FROM Orders;

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You have defined a function with an argument and are not using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below

```
CREATE FUNCTION OrderFulfilmel(average int) RETURNS DOUBLE Deterministic
BEGIN
  DECLARE var_name DECIMAL(10,2);
  SET var_name = 0;
  SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(ShippedDate, OrderDate)) INTO var_name
    FROM Orders;
  RETURN var_name;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why your function would have an argument.  So, I'm thinking:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS OrderFulfilmel//

CREATE FUNCTION  OrderFulfilmel ()
    RETURNS DOUBLE Deterministic
BEGIN
    DECLARE @diff DOUBLE;

    SELECT @diff := AVG(DATEDIFF(ShippedDate, OrderDate)) AS averageDay
    FROM Orders;

    RETURN @diff;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, it shouldnt have an argument. Thanks.